# Vue 2 v-if not working after input changed

Tags: vue.js

Maybe I'm doing it wrong but while binding v-if to two distinct input fields it only works if the input values hasn't changed.

```js
var app = window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#admin-app',
  data() {
    return {
      language: "en"
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.7/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.7/vue.common.js"></script>

<div id="admin-app">
  <select id="language" name="language" class="form-control" v-model="language">
    <option value="ro">Romanian</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
  </select>


  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Test RO" v-if="language == 'ro'" />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Test EN" v-if="language == 'en'" />

</div>
```

As soon as one of the input fields has changed the v-if does not seem to work anymore. Although the "language" value changes when another option is selected.

Comment: I just ran your code snippet and it works perfectly

Comment: @Jeff I had to read the question two or three times to understand what the OP was asking.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VueJS appears to be extrapolating the inline input value as needing to be bound.  I suspect that the input value is bound to the language prop.  As a result, you can no longer safely evaluate your if condition once a value has been changed.

A workaround to this is to give both inputs explicit models via v-model.  This correctly allows for both your conditional display and your input binding.

```js
var app = window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#admin-app',
  data() {
    return {
      language: "en",
      test1: "Test RO",
      test2: "Test EN"
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.7/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.7/vue.common.js"></script>

<div id="admin-app">
  <select id="language" name="language" class="form-control" v-model="language">
    <option value="ro">Romanian</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
  </select>


  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="test1" v-if="language == 'ro'" />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="test2" v-if="language == 'en'" />

</div>
```

Comment: I've managed to find another simple workaround. I've wrapped the input fields inside a <div> tag and build the v-if condition directly on the if.

Comment: @TudorRavoiu absolutely, that would work as well.  It has something to do with the combination of the value and the evaluatory statement.  Moving the evaluation off of the input would accomplish the same thing.